# postgresql prefix matching not using indexes

Tags: postgresql, select, indexing, postgresql-9.3, prefix

I have a large postgresql table (T) that has a small varchar(50) column (C), and there's a btree index on C

neither of the following use the index, and both take a considerate amount of time:

```
select * from T where C like 'myprefix%'
select * from T where C ~ '^myprefix'
```

how can I make such queries faster? Am I doing anything wrong? Is there some other kind of extension/index that will help? My pattern are always the prefix (anchored to the left)

Comment: How did you create the index? Can you provide the `CREATE INDEX` command you used?

Comment: Check out the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations

Comment: I created the index using `create index iname on T(C)`, from the link you posted it seems I have to drop it and use `create index iname on T(c varchar_pattern_op)`, is that correct?

Comment: Test it out for yourself.

Comment: I guess, it is already answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations) .